# Debugging a single test function in buffalo

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, goland, buffalo

Is there a way to Debug a Single [ActionSuite](https://github.com/gobuffalo/suite) Test in an IDE like Goland or VSCode?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: In vscode , the Go plugin by microsoft willl give option to debug test, it will show an underlined text above you test funtion asking you to debug or run test

Comment: This applies for me for e.g. the func Test_ActionSuite(t *testing.T)  but not for a ActionSuite method like: func (as *ActionSuite) Test_AdminUsersResource_Show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from GoLand 2018.3 ([release candidate](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/) at the time of writing this), you can use the built-in testing framework as you do with the "testing" package today.